# Can't chain the functions for IO monad, have to use "do" instead

Tags: haskell

Could anyone explain why can't I do this:

```
getHeaders :: String -> IO ResponseHeaders
getHeaders url = parseUrl url >>= withManager . httpLbs >>= responseHeaders
--getHeaders url = parseUrl url >>= (\x -> withManager $ httpLbs x) >>= responseHeaders -- doesn't compiler either
```

and have to do this instead:

```
getHeaders url = do
  req <- parseUrl url
  res <- withManager $ httpLbs req
  return $ responseHeaders res
```

due to the error:

```
Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    Expected type: Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
                   -> IO ResponseHeaders
      Actual type: Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
                   -> ResponseHeaders
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `responseHeaders'
    In the expression:
      parseUrl url >>= withManager . httpLbs >>= responseHeaders
```

And is there any way to make it work with `>>=`, not `do` ?

**update:**

Indeed, adding **return** makes it work. However, I don't understand why I can chain them as they have different types of Monads. As far as I am concerned, they can't be chained with `>>=` because the return type of the left expression is not the same as the input the right expression accepts. Look:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-1.2.4/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:parseUrl

```
parseUrl :: Failure HttpException m => String -> m (Request m')

withManager :: ResourceIO m => (Manager -> ResourceT m a) -> m a
```

Comment: Does this work: `getHeaders url = parseUrl url >>= \req -> withManager (httpLbs req) >>= \res -> return $ responseHeaders res` ?

Answer (score 7):

You forgot the return in your translation using `>>=`. The correct code is:

```
getHeaders url = parseUrl url >>= withManager . httpLbs >>= return . responseHeaders
```

This is required because `(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b`, but in your case, `responseHeaders` gives back a value of type `ResponseHeaders`, which doesn't match the `IO b`. With the return, you "lift" that value in the IO monad, so you get `IO ResponseHeaders` and the types match.

But, because `a >>= return . f` is equal to `fmap f a` for all `f` and `a`, this can also be written as:

```
parseUrl url = fmap responseHeaders $ parseUrl url >>= withManager . httpLbs
```

Comment: also `return . responseHeaders` can't be replaced with `return $ responseHeaders` because it will mean that there is no variable in there, correct?

Answer (score 1):

`responseHeaders` returns `ResponseHeaders` while you need to return an `IO responseHeaders` from the last call to `>>=`.

You can use:

```
getHeaders url = parseUrl url >>= withManager . httpLbs >>= (return . responseHeaders)
```